# "Add Basemap" button is inactive

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online-basemaps

I have an issue while trying to add basemaps: the relevant button is inactive (take a look at the attached screenshot).

How can I solve this?

[image]

I am using the ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 on Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, have Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 installed, and my pc is connected to the internet.

I have also run an ArcGIS Connection Test and the results are as follows:

> Proxy Server Test - Failed    Reason Unknown.
>
> Download Speed Test - Failed      Test site unreachable.
>
> Network Latency Test - Undetermined   Reason Unknown.
>
> Network Route Test - Failed   Reason Unknown.

I tried to connect ArcMap with arcgis.com but I receive the warning:

> Unable to connect to the selected Portal for ArcGIS

[image]

Comment: This Esri help article (including link in the Cause section) suggest a variety of troubleshooting steps and workarounds: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013300

Comment: Another route to check is your firewall and/or virus protection software, they may be interfering, also there was a system wide [security update](https://support.esri.com/en/https_only) by ESRI which may be an issue as I see you are using the old Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:-

1. Close ArcMap
2. Navigate to the ArcGIS Administrator > Advanced > Manage Portal connections
3. Check if `https://www.arcgis.com` is listed or not, if yes hit connect and relaunch ArcMap, and If not listed follow the next step
4. Add > (Add `https://www.arcgis.com`) > Click Ok > (Select the added URL and click connect) > Save.
5. Relaunch ArcMap

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried to connect ArcMap with https://www.arcgis.com but I receive the warning "Unable to connect to the selected Portal for ArcGIS". I attach this printscreen as a picture on my question.